# For a non square matrix, can you tell what space it is in by looking at the size?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In a $3\times3$ matrix, it is obvious that $n$ is $3$ for $\Bbb R^n$. Then, for a matrix that is $4\times3$, is $n$ related to the number of rows or the number of columns? What about a $3\times4$ matrix? Does it depend on which values are in the matrix?

Comment: "Can you tell what space **it** is in?"  Can you elaborate?  What do you mean by **it**?  Are you talking about the row space?  The column space?  Something else entirely?  I'd say that an $n\times m$ matrix is an element of $\Bbb R^{n,m}$, just as how a $3\times 3$ matrix is an element of $\Bbb R^{3,3}$, not an element of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: In the rank nullity theorem, what is the $n$ in $n = dim(row(A)) + nullity(A)$

Comment: In the [rank nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) the $n$ is the dimension of the domain of the transformation, i.e. the number of columns of the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

An $m\times n$ matrix is always associated with a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$.

- Column Space($A$) = Range ($T$) $\subset \mathbb{R}^m$
- Row Space($A$) = Column Space($A^T$) $\subset \mathbb{R}^n$
- Null Space($A$) = ker($T$) $\subset \mathbb{R}^n$